# How do I change the depth for the Stockfish engine in python?

Tags: python, chess

I've searched anywhere for this info, and only found a broken link to an old stockfish support page which doesn't work anymore.
I can't seem to figure out how to change the depth parameter at which stockfish minimaxes via my python program. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share some code to where you "talk" to Stockfish? The usual UCI command to send to the engine is something like 'go depth 5' and it will search to depth 5.

Comment: `engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("C:\Stockfish\stockfish_20090216_x64_bmi2")
        result = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=1))

        engine.close()`

This is basically where i communicate with Stockfish. The depth limit doesn't really do anything tho, so it's probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have done on Windows 10, which works in 2022:

1. Go to [stockfishchess.org](https://stockfishchess.org/download/) and download the latest version of Stockfish
2. Extract the zip file, and move it to some folder such as `C:\Users\YourName\Documents`
3. Open PowerShell and run the following command:

   ```
   pip install stockfish
   ```
4. Open up a Python shell, and run the following lines:

   ```
   from stockfish import Stockfish

   exe_path = r"C:\Users\YourName\stockfish\stockfish_15_x64_avx2.exe" # From step 2
   stockfish = Stockfish(exe_path)

   stockfish.set_depth(20)

   # Depth now set to 20 half-moves
   ```

And there you have it. You can now update the board with `stockfish.make_moves_from_curent_position("e2e4")` for example and run `stockfish.get_best_move()` to get the best move according to the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You have all documentation needed [here](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html) with examples how to use the different inputs and limits to the engine. If it still doesn't work then please provide us with what your code looks like and what output you are getting.

Comment: Yep, I had already read that, thanks. I ended up doing:

`engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("C:\Stockfish\stockfish_20090216_x64_bmi2")         result = engine.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=1))         
 engine.close()`

but it doesn't get any faster, as I think it should with depth 1...

Comment: Have you checked the PV line it gives you as output? How many moves are included there?